# PhantomJS doesn't load image(s) when rendering PDF from HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

Node.js is calling a Phantomjs script which is loading HTML-content and renders html and css fine. Everything works in the browser, but when the script generates the PDF the image doesn't show in the PDF.

PhantomJS

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var path = require('path');
var page = webPage.create();

var system = require('system'),
    filename = system.args[1],
    content = system.args[2];

page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
page.paperSize = {
  format: 'A4',
  orientation: 'portrait',
  margin: '1cm'
}

page.content = content;
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    page.render('/my/domain/upload/'+filename+".pdf");
    phantom.exit();
}
```

Node.js

```
var childProcess = require('child_process'),
      phantomjs = require('phantomjs'),
      binPath = phantomjs.path,
      path = require('path');

      console.log(name);

var childArgs = [
    path.join(__dirname, 'pdfrender.js'),
    name,
    html
]

return Q.all([childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(stderr);
      return Q(err);
})]);
```

It seems like the script doesn't load the image before rendering the pdf or that the rendering ignores the image tag.

Comment: Maybe add a little delay before `render`?

Comment: Well, I did add a timeout which didn't work. Even tried with 10secs before rendering. But I feel like onLoadFinished should do the job. Which it doesn't.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this?

Comment: No I didnt. Sorry.